# JSONDecodeError - request.body returns empty string Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, jsondecodeerror

I am trying to access some JSON data from my views.py page but it seems i'm sending empty strings?

**My JS code**

```
document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = () => {
    
    const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value
    const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value
    const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body').value

    fetch('/emails', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        recipients: String(recipients),
        subject: String(subject),
        body: String(body)
      })
    })

    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {

      load_mailbox('sent');
      console.log(result);
    });

    return false;
  };
```

**What i was trying to replicate:**

```
fetch('/emails', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: 'baz@example.com',
      subject: 'Meeting time',
      body: 'How about we meet tomorrow at 3pm?'
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
    // Print result
    console.log(result);
});
```

recipient, subject, and body are expected to be strings, given that i am grabbing mine from a form and have them in a variable i thought to convert them to strings

**Template  **

```
<form id="compose-form" action="{% url 'compose' %}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="compose-submit"/>
        </form>
```

**URL**

```
path("emails/", views.compose, name="compose"),
```

**Views.py**

```
    data_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8') 
    data = json.loads(data_unicode)
```

when i debug this is what i get:

> (return) body: b' '

> data_unicode: ' '

Comment: It should be `request.data` instead of `request.body` & you don't have to decode `request.data`, [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts **bytes** or **string** so directly pass `request.data` inside `json.loads` eg **`data = json.loads(request.data)`**

Comment: `Exception Type: AttributeError at /emails/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'` this is the error i got from that

Comment: Try to print `request.body` & `request.data` check which one giving data

Comment: Or you can try like this `json.load(request)['recipients']`